# How do I pass a value from js to python?

Tags: javascript, html, django, aframe

There are buttons for selecting relief and background in The a-frame window. You must pass the values of the JS variable to the python variable to save to the database. How to pass value to django from JS code of button selection?

May is variable, `skyEl.setAttribute ('src', '#blank')` assign Python variable

```js
var sceneEl = document.querySelector('a-scene');


AFRAME.registerComponent('foo', {
  init: function () {
    var skyEl = sceneEl.querySelector('a-sky');
    //Changing color using JQuery here
    $(document).ready(function(){
      let color, src,mtl, terrain, text1;
   $("#text1").click(function(e){
     var x = document.getElementById("fname").value;
        //document.write(x);
        document.getElementById("output").innerText = x;

        return false;
   });
      $("#color button").click(function(e){
        color = e.currentTarget.className;
        skyEl.setAttribute('src', '#blank');
        skyEl.setAttribute('color', color);
        {{ background }} = color;
      });

 $("#picture button").click(function(e){
        src = e.currentTarget.className;
        skyEl.removeAttribute('color');
        skyEl.setAttribute('src', '#'+src);
      });
      $("#terrain button").click(function(e){
   var skob = sceneEl.querySelectorAll('.obj_model');

        terrain = e.currentTarget.className;
  mtl = e.currentTarget.name;

  for (let index = 0; index <= skob.length; ++index) {
  //alert(mtl);
  //skyEl.setAttribute('color', '#1fa9e3');



    skob[index].setAttribute('src', '#'+terrain+'-obj');
 skob[index].setAttribute('mtl', '#'+mtl);
 if(terrain=='city'){
 skob[index].setAttribute('scale', '30 120 35');



 }
 else
 {
  skob[index].setAttribute('scale', '5 10 5') ;
  }
}


      });

    });
  }

});

      sourceURL=pen.js
```

```html
<form method="post">
 <div id="left" >
  <div id="select">
<div id="cssmenu">


                {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" placeholder="title" name="title">
        <input type="text" placeholder="body" name="body">
        <input type="text" placeholder="background" name="background">




    <ul>
 <li class='has-sub'><a href='index.html'><span>Terrain</span></a>
        <ul>
      <div id="terrain">
                <button onclick="this.disabled=true;" name="city-mtl" value="City" class="city">City</button>
                  <button onclick="this.disabled=true;" name="mars-mtl" value="Mars" class="mars">Planet</button>

      <button type="button"name="dey-mtl" value="Forest" class="dey">Forest</button>
     </div>


          </ul>
     </li>


               <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Background</span></a>
          <ul>
        <div id="color">
          <button type="button" style="background-color:#c6aa99" class="#c6aa99"></button>
          <button type="button" style="background-color:#E1A600" class="#E1A600"></button>
          <button type="button" style="background-color:#290942" class="#290942"></button>
          <button type="button" style="background-color:#9392D2" class="#9392D2"></button>
          <button type="button" style="background-color:#1fa9e3" class="#1fa9e3"></button>
    </div>
   <div id="picture">
   <button type="button" style="background:url(icon/star.ico)" class="star"></button>
     <button type="button" style="background:url(icon/cit.ico)" class="city"></button>
          <button type="button" style="background:url(icon/mars.ico)" class="mars" ></button>
      <button type="button" style="background:url(icon/cosmos.ico)" class="cosmos"></button>
      <button type="button" style="background:url(icon/dey.ico)"  class="dey"></button>
      <button type="button" style="background:url(icon/jungle.ico)" class="blue" ></button>
       <button type="button" style="background:url(icon/wasteland.ico)" class="wasteland" ></button>


     </div>



        </li>

 </ul>




          </ul>
     </li>
      <button type="submit" value="save">SAVE</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>




<a-scene id="aframe" foo>
  <a-assets>
    <!-- Images. -->
 <img id="star" src="https://ucarecdn.com/30d7b1e6-2867-4396-a64d-8fb41e69ce0d/">
    <img id="city" src="https://cdn.aframe.io/360-image-gallery-boilerplate/img/city.jpg">
    <img id="cosmos" src="https://ucarecdn.com/34a5bbdb-1820-44c3-a848-26acd9356bbe/">
    <img id="sechelt" src="https://ucarecdn.com/40714251-095c-407e-9b5f-76f361db3b78/">
    <img id="blank" src="https://ucarecdn.com/fc2d2aa9-08b0-4d05-931c-85b78130d758/">
 <img id="mars" src="https://ucarecdn.com/4496c535-1b3d-4c1c-a24f-8fa6bcfb895a/">
 <img id="dey" src="https://ucarecdn.com/1bbbf75b-cc02-450a-91af-e528a6eaf8a1/">
 <img id="blue" src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/3/2929/33929340355_1fb4ecf6e0_k.jpg">
 <img id="wasteland" src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4556/24549684008_5b18834af3_o.png">





      <img id="cobblestones" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/698891c8-2abb-4520-a188-67e9ab3be5ef%2FFloorStreets0072_1_270.jpg?1509915918092" crossorigin="anonymous" />
      <img id="moon" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/698891c8-2abb-4520-a188-67e9ab3be5ef%2Fevol_moon_2048x1024.00252_print.jpg?1509947414949" crossorigin="anonymous" />
      <img id="envmap" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/698891c8-2abb-4520-a188-67e9ab3be5ef%2Fscreenshot-codevember%20sword-1509947893116.jpg?1509947964544" crossorigin="anonymous" />



 <img id="blur-image" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/daae73ed-1502-4527-b809-03c18d6fb3e5%2Fblur.png?1503612651214">

        <a-asset-item id="street-lamp-obj" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/10eac27a-eba4-4e00-be20-e744cb21afd2%2Fmodel.obj?1503963016964"></a-asset-item>
        <a-asset-item id="street-lamp-mtl" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/10eac27a-eba4-4e00-be20-e744cb21afd2%2Fmaterials.mtl?1503963017033"></a-asset-item>

        <a-asset-item id="city-obj" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/10eac27a-eba4-4e00-be20-e744cb21afd2%2Fcity-block.obj?1504041197187"></a-asset-item>
        <a-asset-item id="city-mtl" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/10eac27a-eba4-4e00-be20-e744cb21afd2%2Fcity-block.mtl?1504041197228"></a-asset-item>

 <a-asset-item id="dey-obj" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/f20b51e2-bcd3-47c9-8cd2-8928357227f0%2Flowpolytree.obj?1541822463835"></a-asset-item>
 <a-asset-item id="mars-obj" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/f20b51e2-bcd3-47c9-8cd2-8928357227f0%2Fmountains.obj?1541911076654"></a-asset-item>
  <a-asset-item id="manufacturable-obj" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/f20b51e2-bcd3-47c9-8cd2-8928357227f0%2Fdebris.obj?1541911093399"></a-asset-item>
        <a-asset-item id="dey-mtl" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/f20b51e2-bcd3-47c9-8cd2-8928357227f0%2Flowpolytree.mtl?1541822474000"></a-asset-item>
 <a-asset-item id="mars-mtl" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/10eac27a-eba4-4e00-be20-e744cb21afd2%2Fcity-block.mtl?1504041197228"></a-asset-item>
        <a-mixin id="transition" dur="7000" direction="alternate" repeat="indefinite" easing="ease-out-cubic"></a-mixin>
  </a-assets>
  <a-sky id="sky" color="skyblue" ></a-sky>


<a-entity id='text-container' position="0 1.6 -0.5">  </a-entity>
    <a-entity id="output" text="value: output; align: center;" position="0 0 0"></a-entity>

      <a-plane id="ground" position="0 0 0" rotation="-90 0 0" width="100" height="100" color="#00FF00" material="roughness: 1;"></a-plane>


      <!-- Cityscape -->

      <a-obj-model class="obj_model" id="city-scape-left" position="-55 0 -40" rotation="0 90 0" scale="30 65 35" src="#blank" mtl="#city-mtl"></a-obj-model>
      <a-obj-model  class="obj_model" id="city-scape" position="-5 0 -40" rotation="0 90 0" scale="30 35 35" src="#blank" mtl="#city-mtl"></a-obj-model>
      <a-obj-model  class="obj_model" id="city-scape-right" position="50 0 -40" rotation="0 90 0" scale="30 65 35" src="#blank" mtl="#city-mtl"></a-obj-model>

      <!-- Street Lamp -->
      <a-entity id="street-lamp">
        <a-obj-model id="street-lamp-model" position="2 2 -5" rotation="0 180 0" src="#street-lamp-obj" mtl="#street-lamp-mtl"></a-obj-model>
        <a-light id="street-lamp-light" position="1.4 3.6 -5" type="point" intensity="0" color="#00E6FF">
          <a-animation attribute="light.intensity"
                       from="0"
                       to="1"
                       >
          </a-animation>
        </a-light>

        <a-image id="light-bulb-image" position="1.4 3.6 -5" rotation="-90 0 0" scale="0.6 0.6 0.6" opacity="0" src="#blur-image">
          <a-animation attribute="material.opacity"
                       from="0"
                       to="1"
                       >
          </a-animation>
        </a-image>
```

Answer (score 1):

I did this with AJAX in the function below. A value is fetched from the HTML page using jquery, assigned to a variable and sent to Python function to be processed in the web server. Hope this helps.

Js function:

```
$("#product_enable").on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $this = $(this)
      url = "{% url 'productregister:product_register_disable' %}"
      var productregister_id = $("#form_productregister_id").val(); # Fetching the value from HTML page and storing in productregister_id variable in jquery.
      var product_status = $("#id_product_status").val(); # Fetching the value from HTML page and storing in product_status variable in jquery.
      if (product_status == "deactive") {
          var result = confirm("Are You Sure You Want To Activate This Product?")
          if (result == true) {
            $.ajax({
              url: url,
              type: 'POST',
              data: {
                'productregister_id': productregister_id, 'product_status': product_status, # Javascript variable (productregister_id) assigned to request as data towards python webserver.
              },
              success: function (data) {
              location.reload(true)
            }
          });
        }
      }
      });
```

Python method:

```
def product_register_disable(request):
    product_id = request.POST.get('productregister_id') # The variable sent from javascript in request object is captured in product_id variable in python function.

    # From here you can use this variable (product_id) in your python function.

    product_instance = Productregister.objects.get(id=product_id)

    if product_instance.product_status == "active":
        product_instance.product_status = "deactive"
        product_status = "deactive"
        product_instance.save()
        return render(request, 'productregister/product_status.html', {'product_status': product_status})
    else:
        product_instance.product_status = "active"
        product_status = "active"
        product_instance.save()
        return render(request, 'productregister/product_status.html', {'product_status': product_status})
```